# How should I structure my multiple observations per person data in R for computing OLS and quantile regression?

Tags: r, matlab, regression, quantile

To analyze the data of an eyetracking experiment I preprocessed the data using Matlab and now I wanna conduct regression analysis in R. OLS Regression and quantile regression to be specific.

For a single test person in this case "vp31" I started like this:

```
    # load file
dikablis <- read.table("vp31.txt", sep="\t") # load it

# generate col names
colnames(dikablis) <- c("area","start","end","duration")
```

I have succeeding observations for every person, as reflected by the ascending starting times. To be precise my data looks now like this:

```
          area start  end duration
1    speed     0  200      200
2 attitude   200  400      200
3    speed   400  680      280
4 attitude   680 1200      520
5    speed  3840 4200      360
6 attitude  4200 5160      960
```

Then I try to compute the regression:

```
Call:
lm(formula = duration ~ area, data = dikablis)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-490.1 -218.8  -63.9  118.7 3829.9 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    650.07      22.26  29.202  < 2e-16 ***
areafma       -344.35     103.73  -3.320 0.000953 ***
areahead_pfd  -226.19      51.39  -4.402 1.26e-05 ***
areaheight    -191.25      37.88  -5.049 5.81e-07 ***
areaspeed     -248.75      41.03  -6.063 2.29e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 379.1 on 640 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0838,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.07807 
F-statistic: 14.63 on 4 and 640 DF,  p-value: 1.911e-11
```

Hopefully I am doing it right until here? I am impressed as  R is smart and automatically dummy codes the categorical variable Area of Interest. However is there a way to set the reference level to the first element of a vector including the names of the levels of interest? In this case I would like to have FMA as the reference.

```
aois <- c("FMA", "speed", "attitude", "altitude", "head_pfd")
```

I also extracted a vector with the names of the test persons from Matlab, for example>

```
vps <- c("vp31","vp2")
```

Now on to my bigger question, how should I structure my data to compute the regressions for multiple test persons and how would the regression formula look like? (Don't be confused I just replaced the categorical names in area with numbers here as this sample was generated using an older version of my code)

```
            V1               V2               V3                V4           V5              V6
1 Reg_Area_VP31 Reg_Statime_VP31 Reg_Endtime_VP31 Reg_Duration_VP31 Reg_Area_VP2 Reg_Statime_VP2
2             3                0              200               200            3               0
3             2               40              600               560            2              40
4             1              400              560               160            1             400
5             3              840             1280               440            3             840
               V7               V8
1 Reg_Endtime_VP2 Reg_Duration_VP2
2             200              200
3             600              560
4             560              160
5            1280              440
```

This is my first stackoverflow request, so please don't be to harsh with me :) Looking forward to your input and thanks in advance for your time and help!
Florian

After doing more and more research I wonder whether I have to structure my data like this? So all the information for a moment goes in one row?

```
       id diet exertype pulse time
1   1    1        1    85    1
2   1    1        1    85    2
3   1    1        1    88    3
4   2    1        1    90    1
5   2    1        1    92    2
6   2    1        1    93    3
7   3    1        1    97    1
8   3    1        1    97    2
9   3    1        1    94    3
10  4    1        1    80    1
11  4    1        1    82    2
12  4    1        1    83    3
13  5    1        1    91    1
14  5    1        1    92    2
15  5    1        1    91    3
16  6    2        1    83    1
17  6    2        1    83    2
18  6    2        1    84    3
19  7    2        1    87    1
20  7    2        1    88    2
21  7    2        1    90    3
22  8    2        1    92    1
23  8    2        1    94    2
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I found the answer myself.. In science it is common practice that observations are listed in rows. So my proposal from the last paragraph led in the right direction ;)